# How to handle mysql table size which is more than 2 GB

Tags: mysql, server

I have one table in MySQL server. Which reaches to 2 GB every 1 week. I generally take a backup of that table and delete the data. Please suggest if any other best solution is there for this problem.

Few Doubts I have:

1) Shall i move this particular table to some other NoSql Db like mongoDb or Cassandra ?
2) Will increasing the MySQL server size may help in this problem?

Comment: Your question has absolutely no details to provide any suitable solution. Start with providing details like what is the purpose of the table; what kind of data is stored; result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ..` statement etc.

Comment: And why is a 2GB table a problem?

Comment: *"Please suggest if any other best solution is there for this problem."* Consider RANGE partitioning ... Then you can drop a  partition and delete the data within almost "realtime (instant)" .. to select the current data you could use`SELECT * FROM table USING PARTITION` ...` assuming you partition per week and your MySQL version offcource supports this..

Comment: @Jyoti: also, what version of MySQL are you using? Execute `select version()`

Comment: @BobJarvis 2 GB size is making problem because like this more tables are also there and while altering or fetching the table details it is taking alot of time. Mysql version is 5.5.

Comment: Which OS are you using and which disk partition? i assume your question is that you fear into running into the max file disk partition size?    MySQL partitioning  would/should solve that..

Comment: @Jyoti: do you have appropriate indexes on your table(s) to support the queries you're running, or is the database being forced into using a full scan of the tables to find the data?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Shall i move this particular table to some other NoSql Db like
>   mongoDb or Cassandra ?

A decision to move data to MongoDB or Cassandra is not a decision to be made just for dumping the data somewhere else. These are stores with different data models and operational concerns than an RDBMS like MySQL.

> 2) Will increasing the MySQL server size may help in this problem?

You look to be somehow constrained by disk size which is surprising as 2 GB is nothing in terms of storage. Your smartphone has much more storage than this. You should increase that and then have an archival policy in place. Or if as others too have pointed out if you are hitting file system size limit then you can go for partitioning which has other benefits too like faster queries if the data is constrained in one of few partitions by where clause.

Comment: i think that topicstarter is more constrained to the max file size of the disk partition and is in fear hitting that limit, MySQL partitioning would/should solve that